# How to type in commands automatically in cmd window at a high speed in order to test program reliability?

Tags: java, batch-file, testing, concurrency

I made a simple chat room application consists of a client.jar and server.jar. After running the .jar file in cmd window, I need to type in some specified command in client part and carriage return to run the application, such as "#connect": connect to the server, "#send XXX": send XXX message to server and broadcast to other connected clients...

Here comes the problems. Actually I want to test how the application works well when there exist concurrency. So I think I need try to let two or more client parts send the command repeatedly and fast. But obviously i cannot achieve manually.

Is there any ways can let the system get the command and send it automatically at high speed? I guess using batch file is suitable for this issue, but I am not sure or how to implement it...

Comment: `cat fileContainingTheCommands.txt | yourProgram`.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your reply. What should be the content format of fileContainingTheCommands.txt. Just the text of command line by line? Or if I want to execute one specific command for 1000 times, using the for loop or any other ways?

Comment: The format is exactly the format that you type into your program.

Comment: `cat` is for Linux, use `type` instead

Comment: @SomethingDark I am still a little confused that when i run the jar file, i need to type in "java -jar client.jar -h Localhost -p 4444 -i Mary"  in the command window first, then the java program can read the parameter "Localhost", "4444" and "Mary" out, finally program will start running and waiting for command. So in this case, do you mean i can run the program through "type fileContainingTheCommands.txt | java -jar client.jar -h Localhost -p 4444 -i Mary" in command window?

Comment: In theory, but now that I'm actually reading the question (I was just correcting Andy before), this will not work unless your jar file accepts input from external files. Otherwise, this is technically GUI manipulation, which batch is incapable of.